# Why did Holika die, even though she had a boon of not being burnt by fire?

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-purana, boon, prahlada

The demoness Holika had a boon that she was invulnerable to fire, but when she was made to sit with Prahalada, she was burnt down.
Is this an example of Gods not fulfilling their boons?

[image: Here is an extract from Vishnu Purana:]

Please site suitable sources to you answer.
Thank you.